# How to add driver to Action?

Tags: animation, rigging

I'm learning to use Blenrig 5 Add-on and i've found some feature that i really like it but I don't know how to make one.
That's about how to add driver to Action.
As you see, by scale *hand_close_L* bone, the *zrig_hand_close* is animated, but i can't find where to config the driver of how to create one.
[image: Driver]
This is the *zrig_hand_close* action.
[image: The hand_close action]
Thank you for taking your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because of wrong keyword so i couldn't find the answer on google before.
But i just found out that it's all about Action Constraint.
More information and simple tutorial [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/rigging/constraints/relationship/action.html)